# Airflow experimental API - dag run never enqueued

Tags: python, airflow

It seems that if I trigger more than one DAG run each second, some of them simply never appear in the admin.

I've tried to set the `run_id` manually and disable the microsecond remplacement, but I always lose some DAG runs.

Is there a setting that allows to trigger a large amount of the same DAG in less than a second?

Comment: To be clear: you would like to know if it's possible to have a DAG which runs every second and if possible, how to make sure that this is done in a robust manner?
I guess for starters your jobs needs to finish in a fraction of a second, but that's trivial.
From this post: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/scheduling-tasks/ it seems that Airflow checks every "couple of seconds", so running every second may not be possible...

Comment: actually my problem is not the execution but the enqueuing.

I use the experimental api to trigger my DAG

but sometime I may want to trigger 20 dag_run  in less than a second 

but in the end i only find 10-15 DAG really scheduled in the admin